# Webservice C# para buscar varios archivos y comprimirlos

Tags: c#, webservice

Buen día!

Disculpen la molestia, he tratado de hacer un webservice que tenga como parametro un nombre de factura, va hacia una carpeta y tome un archivo pdf y otro xml los comprima y retorne el zip como respuesta pero no lo he conseguido, intente hacer que buscara de la siguiente manera y aun asi no pude, en serio disculpen la molestia.

Saludos.

```
namespace BuscadorFacturas
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public Buscador getArchivos(string nomFactura)
        {
            //instanciando el objeto
            Buscador seeker = new Buscador();

            //Obteniendo los archivos del directorio especificado
            string startFolder = "C:/Users/Axiliar_Sistemas/Desktop/facturas";

            //tomando captura de los archivos
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(startFolder);
            IEnumerable<FileInfo> fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            IEnumerable<FileInfo> fileQuery =
                from file in fileList
                where (file.Name).EndsWith(nomFactura)
                orderby file.Name
                select file;

            foreach (FileInfo fi in fileQuery)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fi.FullName);
            }

            return seeker;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Revisa esta [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files)

Comment: No es necesario que te disculpes!!! estamos para aprender. Leiste algo sobre compresion? Probaste algun metodo?

Comment: Si lei un poco sobre la compresión, solo que tengo problema al buscar los archivos dentro de la carpeta de facturas, no se si deba ponerlos en un array o algo, para que al tomar el pdf y xml con determinado nombre los comprima y me devuelva el zip, y con php y js mostrarselo al cliente, solo que aun no se como codificar mi idea, más bien como encontrarlo, en el ejemplo que puse según traes todos los archivos y recorres el arreglo con el select, en teoria eso me devolveria 2 archivos segun yo, y me trae null :(